# ionic 3 dynamic class (ngClass)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ng-class

So I am pretty new to this.
I using Ionic 3 and trying to dynamically choose which class to use based on a condition but I cannot get ngClass to work...
Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <div ng-class="test: data[i].complete ? 'completed' : 'notCompleted'>
      <div class="dueDate">{{ data[i].dueDate }}</div>
      <div class="taskLabel">{{ data[i].taskLabel }}</div>
      <div class="checkBox">
        <img src="{{ data[i].complete_url }}" style="width : 100% ; height : 100%" (click)="CheckBox(i)">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You are using angularjs syntax wih angular, it should be something like this,

```
[ngClass]="test===data[i].complete?'completed':'my-notCompleted'"
```

Comment: okay im now using
<div [ngClass]="(test==data[i].complete )?'completed':'notCompleted'">
and it still doesnt work...

Comment: try the modified one

Comment: Is `test` really part of the condition? Isn't it just `data[i].complete`? I don't know what `test:` means in the question.

Comment: oh i understood your logic wrong, what is the condition that you are checking?

Comment: awesome. i believe that was it..
i ended up using 

<div [ngClass]="(data[i].complete)?'completed':'notCompleted'">

if that ends up helping anyone in the future

Answer (score 3):

[class.x]="condition" adds x class to the element if condition is true

```
 <div  [class.completed]="data[i].complete" [class.myNotCompleted]="!data[i].complete">
```

Comment: Don't write code-only answers, instead, please explain how your code would help solve the OP's problem. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19635069)